# iOS UISplitViewController delegate methods never get called

Tags: ios, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

Hi I am developing IOS application in which I am trying to use delegate methods of `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`. But those methods never get called. 
I did following things.

In detail view controller :

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
splitController.delegate = self;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And I try to access following methods:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
     withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
  forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
NSLog(@"Will hide left side");
}

 -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    NSLog(@"Will show left side");
}

- (BOOL) splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
           inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
NSLog(@"should hide view controller ");
  return NO;
}
```

But it is not working for me. Those methods never get called. Am i doing something wrong. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: If you log the value of `splitController` when you assign the delegate, what does it say?

Comment: Thank you Phillip Mills for you help. I check it and I realise I have to initialise splitController. So I did `splitController  = [[UISplitVIewController alloc]init]` and it is working fine.